No fast forward and rewind while playing file from url
I'm using react player to play file served by my backend through API. File is served using https and it is played. However, despite the available video progress bar I'm not able to fast forward/rewind it. How can I solve that? Maybe file should be served differently?

"Maybe file should be served differently?" - yes, probably. A major part of making "seeking" in media streamed via HTTP work, is to properly handle HTTP Range Requests. Sounds like your current implementation doesn't.
